# How to use OperaChromiumDriver for opera version >12.X

Tags: selenium-webdriver, opera

I understand that to work on opera versions > 12.X, Operachromiumdriver has been developed. At the same time I couldn't get this to work. I downloaded the windows version of operachromiumdriver.exe from https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases but to no avail. Can someone help me with this . Please tell me if my understanding is right.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code you have tried on how you are using the operachromiumdriver.exe

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution running opera 25+ using OperaChromiumDriver.exe.

1. Install Opera 25+ (I installed Opera 25)
2. Download OperaChromiumDriver https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases
3. Extract the zip file to a location on the computer
4. Use the following code to open Opera

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/user/Downloads/operadriver-0.1.0-win32/operadriver-0.1.0-win32.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.google.com");
   driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");
   ```

I have used `new ChromeDriver()`. This will start Opera since we are using `OperaChromiumDriver`. I think this is because the new Opera is based on Chromium and OperaChromiumDriver is a WebDriver implementation derived from ChromeDriver [See  https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver].

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

OperaChromiumDriver now works with Opera 26+ but only with a remote instance so far...  Download and launch the appropriate binary from

[OperaChromiumDriver Binary Releases](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases)

They have examples for Desktop versions in python but here's what worked for me in Java.  Many ChromeOptions do not work though it says they should... you will have to test to know for sure but the setBinary does work.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/opera");

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515"),capabilities);
```

Comment: One can use ChromeDriver as OperaDriver v 0.2.2 (last release for quite some time) only supports up to Opera 32.  See comments https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/17

Answer (score 2):

**Operachromiumdriver**

*Download selenium [Drivers](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/index.html). As their is no direct opera driver, OperaChromiumDriver is based on ChromeDriver, so we are Using [ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) to set binary location of operadriver.exe*

*Chromium-based versions of Opera starting from version 26.*

```
String operaChromiumDriver = "E:\\Drivers\\operadriver.exe";
String operaBrowserLocation = "C:\\......\\opera.exe"

System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", operaChromiumDriver);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary(operaBrowserLocation);        

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
OperaDriver browser = new OperaDriver(capabilities);

WebDriver driver =browser;
driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");
```

thanks to Lukus Answer(1) to complete my work.