# Selenium Webdriver - Opera - Unable to receive message from renderer

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run my Java selenium tests using Opera (version 31). I'm using last version of Selenium Webdriver (2.47.1) and last version of [OperaChromiumDriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver) (0.2.2).
I've tried to use next method to instantiate Opera:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\path\\to\\my\\operadriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And i've tried another method with RemoteWebdriver:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/opera");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515"),capabilities);
```

(these methods are described in answers to this question: [How to use OperaChromiumDriver for opera version >12.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330540/how-to-use-operachromiumdriver-for-opera-version-12-x))

Both methods have the same problem.
Opera opens, but then crushes with next exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
(Session info: Opera with embedded Chromium 0.1889.230)
(Driver info: OperaDriver=0.2.0 (ba47709ed9e35ce26dbd960fb5d75be104290d96),platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86_64
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Firefox, Chrome and IE drivers work as it should be, i have such problem only with OperaChromiumDriver. 
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to instantiate `OperaDriver` like this instead:

```
File operaFile = new File("\\path\\to\\my\\operadriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", operaFile.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver();
```

In my application, `.getAbsolutePath()` works but just specifying the path in `.setProperty` does not. No idea why, since the string output of either is identical.

Unfortunately I am still unable to use `OperaDriver` in my tests because it becomes unresponsive after loading a few pages. This occurs on 3 different machines running different versions of Windows and returns only this error:

```
[SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer:
```

FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, and InternetExplorerDriver all work fine with my tests, so, whatever.