# Opera Webdriver not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera, chromium

I'm using newest opera chromium driver from: https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

I've tried few setups:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", operaDriver);
WebDriver driver = OperaDriver();
```

or according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27387949/6044304

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", operaDriver);
WebDriver driver =  ChromeDriver();
```

Opera browser is started and then i try to use simple click on element:

```
element.click();
```

or some others, but it has no effect. It looks like it found element on page but cannot click on it or whatever. WebDriver dont return any errors but nothing happens on page.

My Opera version - 39.0

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know about Selenium is even if you are not having a element you are trying to click or any other kind of error, there would not be any error thrown by the driver in Java.

Apart from that I want to know whether you are not able to click a particular element or is it not working for any element on that page?
Secondly, I would like to know whether how are you getting that element, by id, css, xpath or something else?

I know this is not the answer to this question. I don't have 50 reputation, so I had to do this here instead of putting it as a comment!! Please ignore.